# How can I resize codes what call Instance in different package

Tags: java

How can I use a instance with short code that is created at a class in different package ?

1.java

```
package a;

class First {

    public Player myplayer;

    public void makeContent() {
        myplayer = new Player();
    }
}
```

2.java

```
package b;

class Two {

    public void useContent() {
        First.myplayer.play(); 
    }
}
```

I feel ClassName.Instance is too long to quick development
How can I resize codes what call Instance in different package

Comment: You should read about scope and several other basic java stuff before anything else.

Comment: In this question , that is some example of create instance

Comment: Your `makeContent`method creates an instance (if it gets called somewhere, of course), and this one goes out of scope just after (and then garbage collected), making it totally useless. Hence the comment on scope.

Comment: umm... If you say about myplayer instance is declared defalut , so that code can access on 2.java? I modified that point

Comment: Avoid accessing static variables of other classes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `First` class needs to be public (as well as the `Two` class if you intend to use in it an external main method for instance).
2. You can't access myplayer the way you do. Instantiate the `First` class, call `makeContent` (but unless you have a reason to have a null `myplayer`, why not do it directly in the constructor ?)
3. Your files must be named after your class name.
4. You have to import packages in order to access their content. As I don't know where the `Player`class comes from, I can only guess that you'll have to do the same for it (and check that this class too is public).
5. Make your instance variables private and provide accessors to them.

Here's a simple example:

First.java

```
package a;

public class First {
    private Player myplayer;

    public void makeContent() {
        myplayer = new Player();
    }

    public Player getPlayer(){
        return myplayer;
    }

    // optional, depends if you want to be able to change the player
    public void setPlayer(Player p){
        myplayer = p;
    }
}
```

Two.java

```
package b;

import a.*;

public class Two {
    public void useContent() {
        First f = new First();
        f.makeContent();
        Player p = f.getPlayer();
        p.play(); 
    }
}
```

And the same goes on to instantiate and use the `Two` class...

Comment: aha I don't used an get & set method ,thank you 
umm by the way 
when I initialize variable using setPlayer method as a=setPlayer(b); 
make a and input b to a ? or make a and use a  as shortcut of b?

Comment: `a=setPlayer(b)` won't compile. `f.setPlayer(b)` will replace f.myplayer with a reference to b. That's why I advised you to read a java book. These are fundamental stuff. You can't learn a programming language without understanding at least its basics.